# Gitlab shows 502 status message and exception message "Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file"

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab

We run the follwoing on a debian 11.8 system:

```
# dpkg -l | grep gitlab
ii  gitlab-ee                      16.7.0-ee.0                    amd64        GitLab Enterprise Edition (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)
ii  gitlab-runner                  16.7.0                         amd64        GitLab Runner
```

After the latest upgrade of gitlab-ee it does not run anymore. The website response ist 502 [image]

In the logs I found many lines like this:

```
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:39:53.299Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/gauge_all_puma_6-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:43:05.910Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/gauge_max_puma_1-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:48:48.758Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/gauge_max_puma_0-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:49:25.184Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/counter_puma_8-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:50:04.281Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/histogram_puma_7-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:50:04.306Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/counter_puma_8-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-23T23:50:43.720Z","exception.class":"IOError","exception.message":"Can't reserve 4096 bytes for memory-mapped file in /run/gitlab/puma/counter_puma_8-0.db: ENOSPC: No space left on device","exception.backtrace":["config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:82:in `block in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:173:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `each'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:172:in `call'","lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:133:in `do_worker_start'"],"user.username":null,"tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":null,"tags.correlation_id":null}
```

But when I check my "run" directory it looks like this:

```
# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  6.5M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md2        906G  609G  252G  71% /
tmpfs            32G   52K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/md1        485M  105M  355M  23% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I already tried to restart gitlab, reboot, prune old docker files, disabled prometheus in gitlab.rb with `prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false` and reconfiguring gitlab and restarting after this. Nothing helps.

How can I investigate this problem further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar problem.

In */var/log/gitlab/puma/puma_stderr.log* I had such errors:

```
Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

My system has got 16GB RAM. I didn't find any reason why the memory couldn't be allocated. Finally I reduced number of worker processes for Puma:

*/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*

```
-- # puma['worker_processes'] = 2
++ puma['worker_processes'] = 1
```

then

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart puma
```

and GitLab is back, up and running.

Though, it's a workaround only. Why it doesn't work with 2 is still unknown for me.

Comment: Same solution here. I have no clue what happened, too.